# Sound via HDMI on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, vlc, hdmi

I've got my Toshiba laptop (Satellite A300) connected to my TV via HDMI. Using VLC 2.2.6, video works just fine.

Currently, I'm trying to output sound to the TV's speakers.

`aplay -l` shows the HDMI playback device as the third one:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC268 Analog [ALC268 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC268 Digital [ALC268 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I was able to play a test sound on the TV using `speaker-test -D plughw:0,3 -c 2` after I've unmuted S/PDIF in `alsamixer`.

Yet, when playing a file with VLC, the only option in `Audio → Audio Device` is "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo". At the moment, sound is played using the laptop's speakers.

How can I have VLC output the sound to the TV's speakers?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## With [`pavucontrol`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pavucontrol) (GUI)

Turns out, I had to switch the *profile* of "Built-in Audio" to HDMI.

I can do that with `pavucontrol`, install it with `pacman -S pavucontrol`.

[image: pavucontrol screenshot]

Now, sound works perfectly on the TV speakers.

Since `pavucontrol` uses [PulseAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio), this has to be installed as well: `pacman -S pulseaudio`. After restarting (PulseAudio's systemd job probably needed to be up), `pavucontrol` can connect to PulseAudio.

---

## With [`pulsemixer`](https://github.com/GeorgeFilipkin/pulsemixer) (TUI)

<kbd>F3</kbd> to go to *Cards* mode, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and use the arrow keys or j/k to select the adequate output, probably `Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output`.

If it does not work, double-check in <kbd>F1</kbd> *Output* mode if the card is not muted (<kbd>m</kbd> to toggle mute state).

<sub>Thanks a lot to user [Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/388654/quas%c3%admodo) for this solution!</sub>

---

## With [`pactl`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pactl.1) (command line)

As described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462670/set-default-profile-for-pulseaudio), you can set the profile also from the command line with

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to get this directly as an output device without having to change the configuration profile?

Comment: Selecting another source for the playback, I successfully manage to get my audio output from monitor working! Thank you, you save my day!!

Comment: Thank you. The pavucontrol option helped me achieve HDMI sound output to my TV on Linux Lite 5.6. Note that there, one can also right-click on the sound/speaker (bottom left), select "Properties", and then click on "Run Audio Mixer". From there, follow the instructions above for typing pavucontrol from the terminal (Configuration->Profile, etc.).