# Set default profile for PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio

How do I set the default profile that is used after each boot, in PulseAudio?

When I boot, sound doesn't work. If I open the PulseAudio Volume Control app, and go to the Configuration pane and select "Analog Surround 4.0 Output" from the Profile drop-down menu, then sound works again. However this only lasts until the next reboot.

How do I configure the system to use that profile in the future after reboots?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add the following to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
set-card-profile <cardindex> <profilename>
```

How do we figure out what to use as `cardindex` and as `profilename`?  Here's one way.  Configure the card so everything is working.  The `cardindex` will usually be 0, but you can find it by running `pacmd list-cards` and looking at the line `index: ...`.  To find the `profilename`, use

```
pacmd list-cards | grep 'active profile'
```

The name of the current profile should appear in the output.  Remove the angle brackets (the `<` and `>`).

You can test your configuration by running

```
pactl set-card-profile <cardindex> <profilename>
```

from the command line to see if it sets the profile correctly, then add it to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Since the index name is dynamic (it can change your PCI device index if you boot with a USB audio device plugged in), you could use `<symbolic-name>` instead of `<index>` (if you run `pacmd list-cards`, the symbolic name is right below the index). Also, the command might fail if the device is missing when starting pulseaudio so it might worth to wrap the command with an .ifexists clause:

```
.ifexists <symbolic-name>
pactl set-card-profile <symbolic-name> <profilename>
.endif
```

Comment: If you have multiple audio devices whose ordering is not fixed, you can also use udev rules to configure a Pulseaudio profile for a device. This allows identifying the device by vendor/product IDs, serial number, or by other means. The rule element for setting the Pulseaudio profile is `ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="<profilename>"`

Comment: suggested an edit: index is dynamic, and in my case changes if I boot with the USB audio plugged in.

Comment: This however does not work when a device is hotplugged (i.e.: a bluetooth headset for instance). Running `pactl...` works, but setting the same command into `/etc/pulse/default.pa` does not have any effect... I'm trying to set `headset_head_unit profile` by default instead of `a2dp_sink` for my headset unit.

Comment: One might also want to check `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` file to see if `/etc/pulse/default.pa` is used as default config and uncomment it if it's not and then reload pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: It's so complicated, man, what's the difference between:
```pactl set-card-profile``` and ```pacmd set-default-sink```

Comment: @PavelTankov, please don't use the comment section here to ask questions.  Instead, use the 'Ask Question' button in the upper-right, and make sure to provide full context for your question.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me and worked to set the card profile correctly on `pulseaudio -k`, but in Ubuntu 22.04 other things than Pulseaudio initialization keeps altering the card profile setting, and I had to do a couple of other things to set it right and make it stay right. The information about that is in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1450325/339875

Answer (score 1):

Ended up writing this to help change the profiles. Only worried about bluetooth but you can edit it to your needs to select other sources in `pactl list cards`.

```bash
index=$(pactl list cards | grep -B1 "bluez_card" | grep -oP '(?<=Card #)\d+')

pactl set-card-profile $index a2dp-sink
# pactl set-card-profile $index off
# pactl set-card-profile $index headset-head-unit
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the command line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` doesn't work for me; it caused an error.

I've just worked around putting a command

```
pactl set-card-profile <symbolic-name> <profilename>
```

in the autostart task of linux, and it works.