# Pulseaudio keeps resetting after logout

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

I had to set PulseAudio through `pavucontrol` since sound did not work. `pavucontrol` shows `Dummy output` as output device (??). So I went to

```
pavucontrol > Configuration > Built-in audio > Analog Stereo Duplex (unavailable)
```

and then it works fine (why is it showing it as `unavailable` if it works??). It also works with `Analog Stereo Output (unavailable)`.

But each time I login, sound stops working, `Dummy output` appears again, and I have to set the thing... again.

Everything worked fine in Fedora 29, but never worked since I upgraded to Fedora 32.

How can I prevent PulseAudio from resetting?

Answer (score 1):

I found these two answers that together fixed my issues:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182294/149203

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462671/149203

These pages suggest to modify the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to get the modifications permanent, but my experience indicates that after a system upgrade this kind of modifications usually gives problems.

So I made the following bash script that fixed my particular problem:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 pactl set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo
 SINK=`pacmd list-sinks | grep 'index' | egrep -o '[0-9]*'`
 pacmd set-sink-port $SINK analog-output-lineout
```

The command

```
 pacmd list-cards | grep 'active profile'
```

allows you to check your active profile (Configuration tab in `pavucontrol`), while

```
 pacmd list | grep "active port"
```

shows you the active port (Output Devices tab).