# Audio stopped working after kernel upgrade

Tags: debian, audio

After routine upgrade/reboot of my Debian Sid workstation i completely lost audio.

My desktop (if it matters) is Cinnamon (gnome derivative) with several added pieces, almost all coming directly from Debian archives (I installed a few things from sources, but they should be completely unrelated to sound).

Sound Settings sees just a "Dummy Output" which explains no sound available
[image: Sound Settings screenshot]

I actually have two audio cards, both correctly seen (at least I se no problem):

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [SAMSUNG]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
mcon@cinderella:~$ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:3ec2] (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1458:5000]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [1458:5000]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [1458:5000]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a2af]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1 [8086:a2ba]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH CSME HECI [1458:1c3a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a282]
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode] [1458:b005]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 [8086:a2e7] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1b.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #19 [8086:a2e9] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1b.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #20 [8086:a2ea] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1b.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 [8086:a2eb] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:a290] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:a292] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:a293] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a294] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a298] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [8086:a2c9]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [1458:5001]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller [8086:a2a1]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller [1458:5001]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH HD Audio [1458:a182]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:a2a3]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1458:5001]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9215 PCIe 2.0 x1 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s Controller [1b4b:9215] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9215 PCIe 2.0 x1 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s Controller [1b4b:9215]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 [8086:0070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev e7)
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Radeon RX 580 [1682:c580]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1682:aaf0]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
mcon@cinderella:~$
```

I also have a (working) webcam which should provide Audio input, but also that is not seen at all:
[image]
All drivers/firmware seem to be correctly installed.

What should I check?

**Update**: I can also connect (pair and trust) an external Bluetooth device (headset), but it will not be seen as additional Audio Device.

It seems ALSA/pulseaudio became completely disconnected from underlying hardware.

**Update2**: issuing `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` "solves" problem, but it will be back at next reboot.

I did not change anything in my setup, but `/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service` seems to be quite recent (Sep 22 21:00) and might have been updated in latest `apt upgrade`.

**Update3**: It seems pulseaudio will not survive a logout/login.
Right after login I have:

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
○ pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ pulseaudio.socket

Oct 10 12:25:16 cinderella systemd[4171]: Starting Sound Service...
Oct 10 12:25:16 cinderella pulseaudio[168659]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Oct 10 12:25:18 cinderella systemd[4171]: Started Sound Service.
Oct 10 12:25:18 cinderella pulseaudio[168659]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Oct 10 21:13:26 cinderella systemd[4171]: pulseaudio.service: Consumed 1min 48.247s CPU time.
mcon@cinderella:~$
```

but I can do:

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ systemctl --user start pulseaudio.service
mcon@cinderella:~$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-10-10 22:45:02 CEST; 3s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 627764 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 38373)
     Memory: 12.9M
        CPU: 315ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─627764 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Oct 10 22:45:01 cinderella systemd[614646]: Starting Sound Service...
Oct 10 22:45:01 cinderella pulseaudio[627764]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Oct 10 22:45:02 cinderella systemd[614646]: Started Sound Service.
Oct 10 22:45:02 cinderella pulseaudio[627764]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
mcon@cinderella:~$
```

... and be happy... until next login.

Comment: What's your DE? If it's KDE check if plasma-pa is installed.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm: I am using Cinnamon (gnome). I will reflect that on OP.

Comment: Is `pulseaudio` enabled at start? If the `systemctl` restart works, try running `systemctl --user enable pulseaudio` and see if your problem is resolved upon next boot

Comment: @ajmeese7: pulseaudio *is* enabled. See "Update3" in OP.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425184/1071040) have any effect on your particular situation?

Comment: @ajmeese7: my home dir is not encrypted, if that's what you mean. OTOH it is on a ZFS FS; I am unsure about how to check that is mounted when pulseaudio tries to start (I see no trace of pulseaudio in dmesg startup logs)

Comment: Give [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/151167/1071040) [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598507/370076) answers a shot and let us know the results, may help us narrow down some possible causes